# How to Grep the complete sequences containing a specific motif in a fasta file?

Tags: linux, grep, bioinformatics

How to Grep the complete sequences containing a specific motif in a fasta file or txt file with one linux command and write them into another file? Also, I want to include the lines beginning with a ">" before these target sequences.

Example:I have a fasta file of 10000 sequences.

```
$cat file.fa

>name1
AEDIA
>name2
ALKME
>name3
AAIII
```

I want to grep sequences containing KME, so I should get:

```
>name2
ALKME
```

Attached is the current way I am using based on the answers I got. Maybe others may find it helpful. Thanks to Pierre Lindenbaum, Philipp Bayer, cpad0112 and batMan.

1. Preprocessing the fasta file first and get each sequence into one line (which is very important)

   ```
   awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' < file.fa > file1.fa
   ```
2. Get rid of the first empty line

   ```
   tail -n +2 file1.fa > file2.fa
   ```
3. Extract the target sequences containing the substring including their names and save it into another file

   ```
   LC_ALL=C grep -B 1 KME file2.fa > result.txt
   ```

Note: Take KME as the target substring as an example

Comment: You  should mention all details in question itself which you have in your google drive file. Also have you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: Yes, but I still missed capturing all the sequences. Thank you for your suggestions and next time I will also include my attempted script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have multiline fasta files. First [linearize with awk](https://gist.github.com/lindenb/2c0d4e11fd8a96d4c345), and use another **awk** to filter the sequence containing the motif. using grep would be dangerous  a sequence name contains  a short motif.

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' input.fa |\
awk -F '\t' '{if(index($2,"KME")!=0) printf("%s\n%s\n",$1,$2);}'
```

Comment: for bioinformatics you should ask biostars.org or bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -B1 KME file > output_file
```

`-B1` : prints  `1` line before the match as well

Comment: Thank you. This will work after the pre-processing of the multiline fasta file. I didn't preprocess it previously.